# pass query param in mongdb with node express js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, nosql

i am trying to do the equivaleny in mongodb to sql LIKE search, but i cant have the results that i expected, i am follow this mappig [sql to monog](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/sql-comparison/), but the result json is always empty. if i use a  literal string works , but when pass a variable nothing happens

```
app.get("/questions/search/:query", function(req,res){
  var querySearch = req.params.query;
    //res.send(querySearch)

  Question.find({title: /querySearch/ },function(err,docs){
    if(err) res.json(err)
    res.json(docs)
  });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

That find command will search for documents where the title contains the string "querySearch". This doesn't seem to be what you want to do. When you want to use `find` with a regular expression created at runtime, pass a [RegExp](http://nodemanual.org/latest/js_doc/RegExp.html) object.

But please note that searching with regular expressions is slow. When you don't need all the features of regular expressions and only search for whole words, a [text index](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/text-search/) might be the better choice.

Comment: yes, with RegExp works fine, thanks!